# How to use SetNull in raster calculator at ArcGIS Pro 3.2.0

Tags: arcgis, esri

I got a trouble to practice the following ArcGIS code in raster calculator:

SetNull(("%ExistingRegion_new%" + "%NewRegions%"), "%NewRegions%", "Value = 0")

This code is at ESRI documentation: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/analytics/case-studies/suit-lesson-4-pro-locating-and-connecting-regio...

At the 11 part.
I have tried to figure out what happened, but I followed with the instruction in each step, I have no idea why it does not come through. Please help me fix this. Thanks.

I attached the error below:
ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 5, in rcexec_DC684390_0C54_4F14_9EBF_B34DF3F2E1B1
"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 15724, in SetNull return Wrapper
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 010423: does not have valid statistics as required by the operation.
does not have valid statistics as required by the operation.
Failed to execute (SetNull).
Failed to execute (Raster Calculator).